# PC Black Ops: Why aren't my games being saved in theatre mode?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Forgive me if this has been answered elsewhere or if it's a stupid question somehow.  I can't seem to find the answer elsewhere.

I have the PC version of Black Ops.  I've played a few games now (at a rough guess - ten or so games. I can't actually connect to the server to find out) but my theatre mode screen says 'play some matches' and shows nothing else (no games played)

Answer (score 1):

The theatre mode is currently in "Beta" as stated by Treyarch. Right now, they are only working on official Treyarch servers, but should be expanded "soon." There are over 80 topics on the Gamespot Forums today about this same issue, so you aren't alone in these issues.

Comment: Thanks. It's a relief to know it's not something wrong with my copy of the game.